# A question from number theory (Burton) related to properties of $\sigma$ and $\tau $ function which I am unable to think about

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am self studying David Burton ***Elementary number theory*** and I am unable to prove this relation which is part b of Exercises 7.2.

> If n =$ (p_1)^{k_1} ... (p_r)^{k_r} $ then prove that $\phi(n) \tau(n) \geq $ n .

Can someone please tell how to solve the problem?

Comment: I don’t know what $\tau$ is (number of divisors?), but if it’s multiplicative, you only need to check the inequality on powers of prime numbers.

Comment: Both sides of the inequality are multiplicative, so you need only to prove it for prime powers.

Comment: @Mindlack  Yes $ \tau $ is divisor function

Comment: @B. Goddard thanks , I have done it.

Comment: Please select better (informative) titles for your questions.

Comment: The solution for Number theory by Burton is available here. http://www.americanriver.com/files/burton_elementary_number_theory/Combined%20Solutions%20to%20Burton%20-%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory.pdf